# When Chinese ibus input is on, selecting text on Firefox textareas makes the text disappear

Tags: 14.04, firefox, ibus, input-method

The selected text does not have be Chinese characters, any character just disappears.

The problem happens both on:

- mouse drag
- ctrl + A

selection methods.

I installed the Chinese input through the simplest GUI method possible on the control panel.

This does not happen on Chromium, only Firefox.

Happens with Ubuntu 14.04, and Firefox on `--safe-mode` to turn off all addons.

Similar questions:

- [Selected Text missing when press ctrl or alt](https://askubuntu.com/questions/567212/selected-text-missing-when-press-ctrl-or-alt) , but for me it only happens on Firefox, and for any selection method (mouse drag, ctrl + a)

Comment: Is the ibus-gtk package installed?

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson ibus-gtk and ibus-gtk3 are installed

Comment: Ok. It was a long shot. ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ibus-pinyin now, you can try to use ibus-libpinyin package instead of ibus-pinyin.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @NewUSer while not very clear, I think it was reasonable, as he likely meant "Try `apt-get install ibus-libpinyin`" ? But that alone did not work for me :-s

Comment: This comment is generated by moderation tools. This is to indicate that the answer should be edited and written in well formed and sequential information

Comment: It works? the ibus-libpinyin. see: https://code.google.com/p/ibus/issues/detail?id=1722 and this: https://code.google.com/p/ibus/issues/detail?id=1535&colspec=ID%20Component%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Stars%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary

Comment: @NewUSer, I think you misinterpret the comment. I started a discussion here: https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/13985/this-is-a-comment-comment-is-used-too-much-on-close-votes